# Fasterer yields "Calling argumentless methods within blocks is slower than using symbol to proc" within my validations. How to solve it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am coding my own ERP. For the `People` (model class) I have the following validations:

```
class People < ApplicationRecord

  # some code for N:M relations

  # validations
  validates :aka, presence: { if: proc { |person| person.aka? } },
              uniqueness: true,
              length: { within: 3..25,
                        if: proc { |person| person.aka? } }
  validates :last_name, presence: { if: proc { |person| person.last_name? } },
                    uniqueness: { scope: %i[last_name first_name] },
                    length: { within: 2..100,
                              if: proc { |person| person.last_name? } }
  validates :phone_ext, presence: { if: proc { |person| person.phone_ext? } },
                               length: { within: 1..10,
                                         if: proc { |person| person.phone_ext? } },
                               format: { with: /\A\d{1,10}\Z/i,
                                         if: proc { |person| person.phone_ext? } }
  validates :first_name, presence: true,
                  uniqueness: { scope: %i[last_name first_name] },
                  length: { within: 2..100 }
end
```

As you can see in all the **`if: proc { ....`** lines, they are almost kind of the same stuff. And [fasterer](https://rubygems.org/gems/fasterer) knows about it, that's why I am getting the **Calling argumentless methods within blocks is slower than using symbol to proc** message.

Now, unsuccessfully all day I have trying all day long to figure a way out to solve this Fasterer's message. I have tried lambdas, closures, &:, ->, so I give up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is referring to, for example, `a.map(&:foo)` being faster than `a.map { |o| o.foo }`.

In this context, `validates` will take a method name to check as a symbol. For example, `if: :aka?` instead of `if: proc { |person| person.aka? }`